# Playing PCM audio (wav) on LInux

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa, pcm

I am trying to write a C program that can play PCM wav files directly through the linux sound buffer. The use of this is to synchronize this audio with video frames. For example, for 48kHz audio, I would have to play 2000 samples per frame for a 24FPS video, so I need this sort of control over playback.

I have looked into different libraries but I would like to ask the community, which would be an ideal, somewhat simple library for this application? And if you are able to point me in the direction of sample code that would be very helpful as well. Thank you.

Edit: What I have so far is based on a sample code I found online, that I modified slightly to read .wav files as an argument instead of from standard in. Either way, the audio is constantly buzzing and obviously not playing right.

```
 * Simple sound playback using ALSA API and libasound.
 *
 * Compile:
 * $ cc -o play sound_playback.c -lasound
 * 
 * Usage:
 * $ ./play <sample_rate> <channels> <seconds> < <file>
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $ ./play 44100 2 5 < /dev/urandom
 * $ ./play 22050 1 8 < /path/to/file.wav
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2009 Alessandro Ghedini <al3xbio@gmail.com>
 * --------------------------------------------------------------
 * "THE BEER-WARE LICENSE" (Revision 42):
 * Alessandro Ghedini wrote this file. As long as you retain this
 * notice you can do whatever you want with this stuff. If we
 * meet some day, and you think this stuff is worth it, you can
 * buy me a beer in return.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------
 */

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PCM_DEVICE "default"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int pcm, tmp, dir;
    int rate, channels, seconds;
    snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
    char *buff;
    int buff_size, loops;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc < 5) {
        printf("Usage: %s <sample_rate> <channels> <seconds> <filename>\n",
                                argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    rate     = atoi(argv[1]);
    channels = atoi(argv[2]);
    seconds  = atoi(argv[3]);

    /* Open the PCM device in playback mode */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, PCM_DEVICE,
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't open \"%s\" PCM device. %s\n",
                    PCM_DEVICE, snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Allocate parameters object and fill it with default values*/
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(pcm_handle, params);

    /* Set parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(pcm_handle, params,
                    SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set interleaved mode. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(pcm_handle, params,
                        SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set format. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pcm_handle, params, channels) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set channels number. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(pcm_handle, params, &rate, 0) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set rate. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Write parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params(pcm_handle, params) < 0)
        printf("ERROR: Can't set harware parameters. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Resume information */
    printf("PCM name: '%s'\n", snd_pcm_name(pcm_handle));

    printf("PCM state: %s\n", snd_pcm_state_name(snd_pcm_state(pcm_handle)));

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params, &tmp);
    printf("channels: %i ", tmp);

    if (tmp == 1)
        printf("(mono)\n");
    else if (tmp == 2)
        printf("(stereo)\n");

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &tmp, 0);
    printf("rate: %d bps\n", tmp);

    printf("seconds: %d\n", seconds);   

    /* Allocate buffer to hold single period */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, 0);

    buff_size = frames * channels * 2 /* 2 -> sample size */;
    buff = (char *) malloc(buff_size);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &tmp, NULL);

    fp = fopen(argv[4], "rb");
    fseek(fp, 44, SEEK_SET);

    for (loops = (seconds * 1000000) / tmp; loops > 0; loops--) {

        if (pcm = fgets(buff, buff_size, fp) == 0) {
            printf("Early end of file.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if (pcm = snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, buff, frames) == -EPIPE) {
            printf("XRUN.\n");
            snd_pcm_prepare(pcm_handle);
        } else if (pcm < 0) {
            printf("ERROR. Can't write to PCM device. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));
        }

    }

    snd_pcm_drain(pcm_handle);
    snd_pcm_close(pcm_handle);
    free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

The audio file I'm passing in is expected to be played at a rate of 48kHz on 16 channels.

Comment: Are you also playing the video or is that from some other program?  It seems like you would need to get a frame sync signal from somewhere and then play samples.

Comment: I plan to play the video in the same program. Ideally, the loop would display the frame, play the N (in the example 2000) audio samples, then sleep for the interval (1/FPS) and repeat. I'm not sure if this is possible, but that's how I have been thinking about it.

Comment: The question is too broad and asking for recommendations, so off-topic.  If you make a start and have a specific programming question you can come back and ask it.  Your plan sounds possible.

Comment: I understand, I am new to this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have edited the question with some sample code I have been playing with. Would you mind taking a look if it is in your ballpark?

Answer (score 1):

*This is a sideshow answer that is intended to make you aware of a problem you'll run into eventually, based on your (perfectly reasonable!) assumption that there'd be an integer ratio of audio sampled to video frames.*

> For example, for 48kHz audio, I would have to play 2000 samples per frame for a 24FPS video, so I need this sort of control over playback.

The problem you're going to run into inevitably is, that in a PC, if there's separate audio and video devices, the sound card and the graphics card each have their very own clock oscillators and these oscillators are not locked with each other. Which means that on a PC in practice for 24FPS video and 48kHz sampling rate the sound card will not play back (or record) exactly 2000 samples to a frame.

This is just a fundamental shortcoming of PC architecture, with different devices covering different media.

Of course if you're sending audio over the same device as video, like with HDMI, DisplayPort or SDI carrying both video and audio, that fundamental issue does not emerge. *But for general purpose hardware you must be ready to deal with it!*

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll continue researching ways to synchronize as much as possible.

Comment: @newmsrd I recommend looking into how media players like VLC and mplayer are doing it; they face – obviously – this very problem.

Answer (score 0):

To read the PCM audio from a wav file, it is best to use a library to decode the audio data from file. As your code didn't decode the audio data, the wav file's data sounds buzzy !

gtkIOStream uses libsox to decode many different types of audio files. If you were to use C++, then it would be like so to open the file for reading and to find it vitals, like channels, sample rate, etc :

```
int res=sox.openRead(name);
if (res<0 && res!=SOX_READ_MAXSCALE_ERROR)
    return SoxDebug().evaluateError(res);

unsigned int fs;
if (sox.getFSIn()!=Playback::getSampleRate()){
    cout<<"sample rate mismatch, file = "<<sox.getFSIn()<<" Hz and ALSA = "<<Playback::getSampleRate()<<endl;
    cout<<"fixing sample rate mismatch"<<endl;
    if ((res=setSampleRate(sox.getFSIn()))<0) // set ALSA's playback saple rate
        return ALSADebug().evaluateError(res);
    fs=Playback::getSampleRate(); // read back ALSA's sample rate
}
cout<<"rates are now, file = "<<sox.getFSIn()<<" Hz and ALSA = "<<fs<<endl;

int ch=sox.getChCntIn();
cout<<"setting ALSA channels to " <<ch<<endl;
// use the ALSA function to set the channels here.
```

In C it would be more like the following :

```
sox_format_t *in = sox_open_read(fileName.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (!in)
    return -1; // some error like this would be better SOX_READ_FILE_OPEN_ERROR;
```

The file's sample rate and various other sound file parameters can be found like so :

```
in->signal.rate
in->signal.channels
```

Now sox uses a 32 bit word, so you should setup ALSA to use 32 bit words with the following format :

```
SND_PCM_FORMAT_S32_LE
```

Now read a 'count' amount of data using sox like so :

```
sox_sample_t buf[count*ch];
size_t readCount=sox_read(in, buf, count);
```

You can then write that buffer to ALSA with snd_pcm_writei.
Don't forget to set ALSA's channels and sample rate for playback.

A full example of C++ playback from many different types of audio files is available in the gtkIOStream [ALSAPlaybackTest.C file](https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/test/ALSAPlaybackTest.C).

If you want a good source for a C setup, reference [ALSA's aplay.c code](https://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-utils.git;a=blob;f=aplay/aplay.c;h=cc51dcb48bba395cdbbe002e38e6d8f0d52872ee;hb=HEAD).